# How do I group data from the database in a DTO?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-transfer-objects

How do I group data from the database in a dto?

For example I want my output to be like this:

```
{
    id: "random-id-tst",
    years: [
        {
            year: 1,
            productIds: ['guid-id-1', 'guid-id-2'],
        },
        {
            year: 2,
            productIds: ['guid-id-3'],
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am struggling and tried many things and got to this point:

```
{
    id: "random-id-tst",
    years: [
        {
            year: 1,
            productIds: ['guid-id-1'],
        },
        {
            year: 1,
            productIds: ['guid-id-2'],
        },
        {
            year: 2,
            productIds: ['guid-id-3'],
        },
    ]
}
```

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid ID{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class OrderLine
{ 
    public Guid OrderID { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set }
}
```

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }        
    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

```
 public class OrderDto
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<YearsDto> Years { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class YearDto
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Guid> ProductIds { get; set; }
}
```

I tried many things but get different errors each time.

This is what I did:

```
var orderLines = (await _context.OrderLine
    .Where(s => s.orderID == orderId)
    .ToListAsync()).GroupBy(ol => ol.Year);


var order = (await _context.Order
    .Where(order => order.ID == orderId)
    .Select(x =>
        new OrderDto()
        {
            ID = order.ID,
            Years = orderLines.Select(ss => new YearsDto()
            { 
                Year = 1,
            }),
        }
    ).FirstAsync());


return order;
```

As you can see I hardcoded `Year` and didnt include `productIds` because for some reason I cant reference `ss.Year` or `ss.Product`, also when I run this, it gives me an error:
`` InvalidOperationException: variable '__Select_1' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[YearsDto]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined ``

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should get you the result you need:

```
            var order = _context.OrderLine
                .Include(o => o.OrderLines)
                .Where(s => s.Id == orderId)
                .First();

            var orderDto = new OrderDto()
            {
                ID = order.Id,
                Years = order.OrderLines.ToLookup(ol => ol.Year).Select(g => new YearDto() {Year = g.Key, ProductIds = g.ToList().Select(x => x.ProductID).ToList()})
            };
```

Comment: Had to make some changes, but it works now! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

In your first group, you probably want someting like

```cs
var orderLines = (await _context.OrderLine
    .Where(s => s.orderID == orderId)
    .ToListAsync()).GroupBy(ol => ol.Year, (key, group) => new { Year = key, Items = group.ToList()});
```

That way, your final object will be an enumerable of anonymous items, containing a property `Year` and a property `Items` that belong to that year.

So your rest of the query (just to make it compile and fetch the data you need) could be transformed into:

```cs
var order = (await _context.Order
    .Where(order => order.ID == orderId)
    .Select(x =>
        new OrderDto()
        {
            ID = order.ID,
            Years = orderLines.Select(ss => new YearsDto()
            { 
                Year = ss.Year,
                ProductsIds = ss.Items.Select(i => i.ProductID)
            }),
        }
    ).FirstAsync());


return order;
```

Comment: Still got the `InvalidOperationException`. Got it working with kebek's answer. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need any extra data in your OrderDto except it's ID(which you already have), you can do it like this:

```
var years  = ( await _context.OrderLine
    .Where(s => s.orderID == orderId)
    .Select( ol => new {ol.Year, ol.ProductID})
    .ToListAsync())
    .GroupBy(ol => ol.Year)
    .Select(g =>  new YearDto 
    { 
         Year = g.Key, 
         ProductIds = g.Select(i => i.ProductID).ToList() }
    )
    .ToList();
var orderDto = new OrderDto {ID = orderId; Years = years };
```

Although you will lose the check that order exists in db, but you can query it separately.